# how to compare one 2d vector string with another 2d vector string for best match?

Tags: c++

I have few states (50 steps) of a game run which look like bellow:

Init State: `State: [(true (cell 1 1 8)), (true (cell 1 2 7)), (true (cell 1 3 6)), (true (cell 2 1 5)), (true (cell 2 2 4)), (true (cell 2 3 3)), (true (cell 3 1 2)), (true (cell 3 2 1)), (true (cell 3 3 b)), (true (step 0))] Hash=1241d9`

```
(move 3 2) State: [(true (cell 1 1 8)), (true (cell 1 2 7)), (true (cell 1 3 6)), (true (cell 2 1 5)), (true (cell 2 2 4)), (true (cell 2 3 3)), (true (cell 3 1 2)), (true (cell 3 2 b)), (true (cell 3 3 1)), (true (step 1))] Hash=123eed
```

I want to make suppose the first two steps together as reference and the other states of the game needs to be compared with this reference state . first it should find out the best match (out of 2 reference states) depending on the highest number of cells same with the reference state for the best match. And then during comparison the first cell of all the different states needs to be compared with first cell of the reference state and so on. After finding the best match if the cells of the one state is exactly same like the reference state then it should print "," on the other hand if the cell is different it should print out the whole cell without any change.

i have already written a code with only one step as a reference and compared each and every cell of other states with the cells of the reference state. my code is given bellow. Now i am stuck with taking multiple state as reference,finding the best match (highest number of cells same as reference state cells) and then comparing with other states of the game.
thank you.
 `

```
int main()
{

    int x=0; //reference node number
    ifstream inputFile("8puzzle_1strun.txt");   // attach input stream to file
    ofstream outputFile("output_8puzzle_1strun.txt");
    vector<string> textLines;   // vector that will store all the file lines
    string line;
    if(!inputFile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't open input file!\n";
    }

    int number_of_lines = 0;
    while(getline(inputFile, line))      // read the text line by line
    {
         ++number_of_lines;
        textLines.push_back(line);    // store each line as vector element
    }

    outputFile<<"Reference Node is: \n " << textLines.at(x) << "\n" <<endl;

    cout << "textlines size:"<< textLines.size()<< endl;

    vector < vector<string> > input_array;

    for (int i=0;i<textLines.size();i++){
        vector <string> input_cell;
        string part=textLines.at(i);
        string token;
        istringstream is(part);

        while (getline(is,token,'[')){
            while (getline (is, token ,',')){
                //cout <<token<<endl;
                input_cell.push_back(token);
            }
        }

        input_array.push_back(input_cell);
    }

    int size_of_array = input_array[0].size();
    cout<<"array size:"<<size_of_array<< endl;

    vector <string> reference_state_cell;
    string token1;
    for (int j=0;j<65;j++){
    for (int k=0;k<5;k++){
    string part1=textLines.at(k);
    istringstream ls(part1);

    while (getline(ls,token1,'[')){
      while (getline (ls,token1,',')){
    reference_state_cell.push_back(token1);

            }
        }
      reference_state_cell.push_back(token1);
     }
     cout << reference_state_cell[j] <<endl;
    }
    // comparing all the states with the reference state//

    for(int f=0; f<textLines.size(); f++){
        for(int j=0; j<65; j++){
            string str1 = reference_state_cell[j];
            string str2 = input_array[f][j];

            if (str1.compare(str2) == 0)    // when two strings are equal
            {
            outputFile << "," ;
            }
            else{                                    //when two strings are not equal
              outputFile<< input_array[f][j];
            }

        }
           outputFile << endl;
    }


}
```

`

the steps should be :

1)first finding out the best match from the reference state( suppose if 8 cells of a state are same to the reference state 8 cells then we take that state out of two reference state and make this single state as our reference state)

2. After picking up only one state(from 2 reference state) we need to compare each and every cells of that state with the other states.
3. During comparison the cells that are same as the refernce state cells we just print "," and the other cells need to be printed out as they are without any change.

4.The same process goes on for all the fifty states of the game.

Comment: Try to formulate your question in terms of programming.  What specific programming problem are you having difficulty with?  Writing out the project requirements is not a question.  Most good questions are not so lengthy.

Comment: okay to be specific how can i find the best match of a string from a bunch of strings? And how to compare each and every elements of a 2d vector string with each and every elements of another 2d vector string? thanks in advance.

Comment: Best match for a string?  Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance